# SmartyPHP with Hip Hop

Tags: php, jquery, performance, smarty, hiphop

i can not seem to find a layman answer to this question i have, so hopefully you can help me.

SmartyPHP application, heavily using Jquery, Ajax.

In region of 1.2 million lines of code and growing by 200k weekly and likely to be 3 million lines before completion.

Application is a network specifically for a few hundred thousands growing to a max of 1 million.

Currently site loads up in under 6 seconds on some tests and on others 15+ seconds!! :(

We are looking at hiphop and are quiet lost, it would be handy if it can compile the code server side and reduce the pressure, but we are

1. Unsure whether it will work with Smarty PHP
2. How to set up - we need to hire a experienced Hip Hop developer/engineer to advise - where?
3. Where to download a unaccustomised copy of the software/module to integrate with our site/application

Thank you for your advice and help.

Answer (score 1):

1. To check for compatibility you can use this resource.  Keep in mind, these are not the only frameworks supported.  For the most part, HHVM will run PHP applications without any issue.

   Framework Compatibility: http://hhvm.com/frameworks/

   Doing a quick Google search I found a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2763) that was opened to add Smart to the framework test system from back in the middle of 2014. Perhaps a further look into this may be of help for compatibility testing.
2. Setting up HHVM is simple and can be done by a server administrator or a developer who is familiar with command line interfaces by following something as simple as a tutorial.

   [Example from digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hhvm-hiphop-virtual-machine-on-an-ubuntu-13-10-vps)
3. You can download a stable version of HHVM straight from their [homepage](http://hhvm.com/) which links to their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Getting-Started).